# Screen splits into 4 after installing Nvidia Driver for 310M

Tags: nvidia

Just intsalled Ubuntu 12.04, but I want to get the most out of my graphics card so I installed the recommended drivers for Nvidia 310M.

When I boot up get to the login screen the display is split into 4 equal parts and each area is a mirror of the other.

Anyone have any ideas how to get a decent driver working for this. I have tried BumbleBee and looked at nearly all the solutions on the forum.

It seems that Nvidia just sucks in general.

Comment: try to remove  xorg.conf file by running the command on virtal terminal or console `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Answer (score 2):

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and install bumble bee it was amazing it 's code ::

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
press enter when asked.
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia

but if you want to download nvidia you can download it from the linux :: 
http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

and don't use recommended drivers from additional driver application in ubuntu it some time be no compatible .

i hope i help you :)